# Monochrome v. Colour logo in search widget

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, nexus-7, motorola-moto-g, google-search

Following Google's recent rebranding, the three Lollipop devices in our household all got the updated search widget.

My wife's 2nd-gen Moto G got the usual coloured one (this image from the web, not a screenshot):

[image: Google search widget]

while her 2nd-gen Nexus 7 and my 1st-gen Moto G got a rather more tasteful monochrome version (screenshot from my Moto G):

[image: Monochrome Google search widget]

Why the difference, and is there any way to swap between the two?

Comment: Could you try to remove this monochrome widget and add the Google search widget again.? BTW, Do you use any third party launchers? Coz, I have Apex launcher and it displayed the transparent Search bar for me even after the logo change. I removed it and added the Google search bar again to my homescreen which had the new design.

Comment: Not using any 3rd party launchers, just the default on each device. I could try removing and re-adding but I don't want to risk losing the monochrome version, which is much preferable to the coloured one :)

Comment: I tried to remove the search bar with new design in my Moto G2 Lollipop 5.0.1 device, but Google Now Laucher won't let me remove the widget anyway. But the search bar was not displayed transparent to me either.

Answer (score 0):

Moto G dual-SIM 16GB first generation here.

I noticed my phone google widget, unlike yours, was displaying the color version of the logo. I've been using Aviate launcher and, before that, used google now launcher. Tested it and, again, colorful version:

[image: Google Now launcher screenshot]

Then I Switched to the default launcher (unlike 2nd gen Moto G, 1st gen does not use Google Now launcher by default) and voilà! there was the monochrome white version of the logo in on the widget.

[image: Clean, monochrome logo with default launcher]

What i can guess is that somehow the widget is themed to match the launcher.

(I Apologize for the possibly bad english; I'm not a native speaker)

Comment: Aha! So if the 2nd gen Nexus 7 uses the Google Now launcher by default (I'll have to ask my wife!), then it's probably as simple as that, isn't it.

Comment: I believe you can always use google now launcher whenever you want the colorful version, but i don't know which other launchers will get you the translucent white widget. 

Keep in mind  that the launcher changes much more of the phone's usability, so you should play around with some and see which one works for you (and/or your wife)

Comment: Hi! You need not to put a note making an apology for bad  English. This is not a forum but a Q&A site and the  users (including you) are imparted the right to propose or make (subjected to 2k points) an edit in a post to fix grammatical mistakes among other things. Just keep up the good work. Thanks!